# error in implementing stack using linked list

Tags: c++, class, linked-list, stack

I'm trying to implement a stack using linked list in cpp. I'm using class to make the linked list but I'm getting the following error and I dont understand why

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

class Stack{
    public:
    int top;
    Stack* next;
    Stack(int data){ //constructor
        top = data;
        next = NULL;
    }
    void push(Stack* &head, int data);
    int pop(Stack* &head);
    bool empty(Stack* &head);
};

void Stack::push(Stack* &head, int data){
    Stack* s = new Stack(data);
    s->next = head;
    head = s;
}

int pop(Stack* &head){
    int x = head->top;
    head = head->next;
    return x;
}

bool empty(Stack* &head){
    if(head == NULL)
        return true;
    return false;
}

int main() {
        class Stack* s = new Stack(1);
        s.push(2);
        s.push(3);
        cout << s.empty(s) << endl;
        cout << s.pop(s) << endl;
        cout << s.pop(s) << endl;
        cout << s.pop(s) << endl;
        cout << s.empty(s) << endl;
}
```

ERROR: request for member 'push' in 's', which is of pointer type 'Stack*' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)

request for member 'empty' in 's', which is of pointer type 'Stack*' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)

request for member 'pop' in 's', which is of pointer type 'Stack*' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)

When I used -> instead of . it said undefined reference to Stack::empty(Stack*&) and undefined reference to Stack::pop(Stack*&)

EDIT: I used -> instead of . and added Stack:: to pop and empty function and it worked but the constructor isn't working

Comment: The first set of errors are typos that you've fixed. Why are you asking about them? They do not belong in a [mre].  The second issue (undefined reference) is a common dup, because you've defniied `pop` and `empty` as global functions (and not members, like `push` is).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use -> whenever you are accessing data member of structure pointed by a Pointer. In your case, try using -> instead of . on s in the main function ()
So, either do

```
Stack s; 
s.push(1);
```

Or

```
Stack* s;
s->push(s,1);
```

Comment: `Stack* s; s->push(s,1);` — This is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says, when you have a `Stack*`, you need to use `->`, and not `.`, like this:

```
s->push(s, 42);
s->empty(s);
// etc
```

However, you probably don't need a `Stack*` here at all, and could just use a regular `Stack` object.

Also, your member functions that are defined outside the class, need to be qualified with the name of the class. So you need:

```
bool Stack::empty(Stack* &head){
```

instead of:

```
bool empty(Stack* &head){
```

like you have already done for the `Stack::push` method.

Answer (score 0):

You 'accidentally' declared a pointer. Change your code like this

```
int main()
{
    Stack s(1);
    s.push(2);
    ...
```